# Cannot exclude from a list items contained in another list with Linq

Tags: linq, list

I have two lists of custom types "Client". I have to merge the two lists avoiding possibnormale duplicates.

 I tried both IEnumerable.Except() method and the "NOT IN" statement via Linq but the returned list has still the elements contained in the other list:

```
var dupes = getFirstList().ToList();   //List<Client>
var search = getUsersList().Cast<Client>().ToList(); //List<Client>

//The returned items are the same as in original dupes list
var unique = dupes.Except(search).ToList();  

//No records are returned, even if debugging I can see that same contactId is in both lists
var u = from k in normalSearch
        where !(from d in dupes
                select d.ContactId)
               .Contains(k.ContactId)
        select k;
```

Why I cannot match the two lists to remove duplicates?

**EDIT:**

For Except method I guess I have to implement the Interface IEquatable to let it work with custom types. But in the case of LINQ statement I still cannot understand why no record is returned, since "ContactId" field is an int in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the linq part (which will be slow as compared to Except) you can try something

```
    from k in search
    where !dupes.Any(d => d.ContactId == k.ContactId)
    select k;
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I thought that in Linq I could "automatically" iterate throuh collections' items without the need of using Any() method.

Answer (score 1):

Except used this way is checking reference equality, so it doesn't matter if those objects have the same `ContactId` or any other fields. (in your code you are using `normalSearch` variable but it's no where there defined)

Comment: Considering the Linq statement, it should work in that case. Any idea why is not returning any data? That should be a normal Linq query over lists.